# Change tab view with button

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, button, tabs

super new to coding. I followed a tutorial on creating tabs and fragments. My app right now has 3 tabs on the toolbar, and when clicked they change to their respective layout. I'd like to now add a button that will take me to those layouts instead of using the toolbar, so I can move it around and place it where I want.

This is what I have in my MainActivity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mSectionsPageAdapter = new SectionsPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

     //Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    setupViewPager(mViewPager);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    SectionsPageAdapter adapter = new SectionsPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new Main2Activity(), "TAB1");
    adapter.addFragment(new Main3Activity(), "TAB2");
    adapter.addFragment(new Main4Activity(), "TAB3");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

So then I added this code for the button. In my XML, I placed the button above the container id so that I can always see it. Ideally, I'd have 3 buttons, each one putting into the container id Main2Activity, Main3Activity, and Main4Activity. Here is just 1 button as I try to figure out how to get the view to change.

```
public void onClickBtn1(View v){
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

    ft.replace(R.id.container, new Main2Activity());
    ft.commit();
}
```

This is also my SectionsPageAdapter page if it helps.

```
public class SectionsPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
    mFragmentList.add(fragment);
    mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
}

public SectionsPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return mFragmentList.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mFragmentList.size();
}
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call [`ViewPager#setCurrentItem`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setCurrentItem(int,%20boolean)) in your on click to go to the index of the item in the viewpager's adapter's list/array:

```
public void onClickBtn1(View v){
    int gotoIndex = 0;
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(gotoIndex, /*smoothscrolling*/ true);
}
```